# MySQL Query fails to return data on connection successful

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to MySQL and I am facing difficulties to get mysqli query to work. I can connect to the database and query on development machine of which everything seeks to work but the query returns no data on capnel. I have read related post on this issue and none of them seems to solve the issue. I really want to know if this is a hosting flaw, PHP version error or my code. Below is my database connection and the query.

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "myuser");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "mypassword");
define("DB_DATABASE", "mydatabase");

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
?>


$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);           
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'sbausers' WHERE email = '$email' AND Password = '$password'";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
if ($row > 0){
    echo 'it works';
} else {
    echo 'it doesn't work';
}
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: You closed your Php tag before execute Query code

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Do you store passwords unencrypted in the database?

Comment: **PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: The connection string is in a different file

Comment: Do you `inlcude` or `require` the other file in this file?

Comment: Anyway, as per the first DUP, your query is incorrect

Comment: @Riggs Please I have already stated that I have read related post but none of the comments seems to actually solve the issue. The question is not also about single quotes or php errors. It runs on development machine alright with codes error set to on.

Comment: _It runs on development machine alright_ I dont see how that is possibe, so I will just have to leave this question to someone else to answer

Comment: If you moved this code from a test to live server. It is most likely that the Userid and Password used on the LIVE database is different to that used on the test machine. ALSO the database server may not be on `localhost`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I have contacted that hosting providers and they are looking into it, I believe that database created is not on localhost

Comment: I find the solutions after digging harder into the issue. I realised that, on linux environment case sensitive really matters to both MySQL database and tables as well as directory structure. I rewrote all the queries making sure all uppercase table names were changed to lowercase. I also found at that, there was a directive in the config file that could be changed to allow uppercase table names to be recognised but that was a little bit cumbersome. Any developer hosting on new linux environment is likely to face this. I wish someone with higher reputation post this as answer. Thanks